# Break point setting color settings

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Anyone know how/where to customize the "Breakpoint Settings" window color for Visual Studio 2015?

I have dark background IDE, and works for the most part, but certain windows are hard to read.  Particularly the "Breakpoint Settings" window is unusable

[image]

Comment: This is obviously not normal. I've flipped my VS 2015 IDE into "dark" mode before, and it doesn't mess up all the windows. I'm guessing that either your settings are corrupted and you should reset them, or you have some kind of super-duper color-themer extension installed that is allowing you to make things unreadable.

Comment: Yes, I am not using the standard "dark ide".  Long story short, I have been using (a slightly enhanced/bastardized version of) [WekeRoad Ink](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/wekeroad-ink) for some time and has served me very well.  Unfortunately VS2015 came with a lot more "features" in the color scheme dept, and things have gone crazy since.  All I'm trying to do is figure out the name of the setting so I can change the txt to be readable and keep WekeRoad scheme

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the colors of "Peak Background" and "Peak Background Unfocused"

Comment: this changes "Peak" window across the board, my peak works fine, it's only the label txt that doesn't (it's in black for some reason and I can't seem to change the txt color